# Filter one column in table in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I want to filter for unique events based on event category= Landing Page Links for dimensions=campaign and source. The entire table is already filtered for certain campaigns and sources. But on this particular column in the table I want event category filter in google data studio report. Is it possible?

I have tried creating calculated fields using case when but it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do but it you want to have different filters for 2 columns in one table, you can use data blending. If you have data source A and wants filter1 on one column and filter2 on the other, blend Source A with filter1 to SourceA with filter2. You just have to configure the Joint Keys properly to make it give the data you are expecting.

Comment: Hey I tried blending but blending only allows me to do Joins which matches the whole values doesnt really allow me to use a way to fiter based on one field may contain other field but may not have 100% match